# Hash string into RGB color

Tags: hash, colors, language-agnostic

Is there a best practice on how to hash an arbitrary string into a RGB color value? Or to be more general: to 3 bytes.

You're asking: When will I ever need this? It doesn't matter to me, but imagine those tube graphs on any GitHub [network page](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/network). There you can see something like this:

[image: git branches]

Where every colored line means a distinct git branch. The low tech approach to color these branches would be a CLUT (color lookup table). The more sophisticated version would be:

```
$branchColor = hashStringToColor(concat($username,$branchname));
```

Because you want a static color every time you see the branches representation. And for bonus points: How do you ensure an even color distribution of that hash function?

So the answer to my question boils down to the implementation of `hashStringToColor()`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A good hash function will provide a near uniform distribution over the key space.  This reduces the question to how do I convert a random 32 bit number to a 3 byte RGB space.  I see nothing wrong with just taking the low 3 bytes.

```
int hash = string.getHashCode();
int r = (hash & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
int g = (hash & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
int b = hash & 0x0000FF;
```

Comment: Although if you want to ensure readable colours (e.g. ensure high enough contrast, and saturation), you're going to have to do a bit more work than that. Might be easier to work in HSV or LAB, and convert to RGB.

Answer (score 28):

For any Javascript users out there, I combined the accepted answer from @jeff-foster with the `djb2` hash function from [erlycoder](http://erlycoder.com/49/javascript-hash-functions-to-convert-string-into-integer-hash-).

The result per the question:

```
function djb2(str){
  var hash = 5381;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + str.charCodeAt(i); /* hash * 33 + c */
  }
  return hash;
}

function hashStringToColor(str) {
  var hash = djb2(str);
  var r = (hash & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
  var g = (hash & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
  var b = hash & 0x0000FF;
  return "#" + ("0" + r.toString(16)).substr(-2) + ("0" + g.toString(16)).substr(-2) + ("0" + b.toString(16)).substr(-2);
}
```

**UPDATE**: Fixed the return string to always return a #000000 format hex string based on an edit by @alexc (thanks!).

Comment: You could also format the color this way: return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")"

Comment: @StuGla: I can't recall if the hex format was part of the requirements; reading it now it doesn't appear to be. Since the question was asked generically, I think the author was more interested in the hashing algorithm than the format of the color string. However, if the context of the question is CSS, yours would be a much cleaner way to do it. Cheers man, thanks!

Comment: @StuGla: This allows for also adding transparency.

Answer (score 17):

I just build a JavaScript library named color-hash, which can generate color based on the given string (using HSL color space and BKDRHash).

Repo: https://github.com/zenozeng/color-hash
Demo: https://zenozeng.github.io/color-hash/demo/

Comment: Thanks! I ported the HSL function from your library to C#, my code can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71083321/740639

Answer (score 10):

I tried all the solutions others provided but found that similar strings (string1 vs string2) produce colors that are too similar for my liking. Therefore, I built my own influenced by the input and ideas of others.

This one will compute the MD5 checksum of the string, and take the first 6 hex digits to define the RGB 24-bit code.

The MD5 functionality is an open-source JQuery plug in.
The JS function goes as follows:

```
function getRGB(str) {
    return '#' + $.md5(str).substring(0, 6);
}
```

A link to this working example is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkophs/hdM8y/16/). Just input a string into the input field and press enter, and do so over and over again to compare your findings.

Comment: Please fix the link

Answer (score 2):

The hashcode returns an `int` that is calculated with a formula that is defined in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()). You can then calculate the modulo of that `int` with 16,777,216 (2^24 = 3 bytes) to get an "RGB-compatible" number.

It is a deterministic calculation so the same word(s) will always have the same colour. The likelihood of hash collision (2 strings having the same colour) is small. Not sure about the colour distribution, but probably fairly random.

Comment: I think hash collisions could be neglected, since when a collision occurs that's not much of an issue as long as you don't need to neighbours colors (like in the example given) to be differnt.

Comment: The randomness of color distribution might be an aesthetic issue.  There are a lot of 'ugly' colors, it might be a practical idea to apply some sort of weight to the components to try to better the pretty:ugly ratio.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Interstingly enough a common representation of hashing functions like sha256 or md5 is as a hex string. Here is a fiddle that uses the 10 6 byte segemnts to create a coloful representaion of and sha256 hash. It uses the last 4 byte segment to determine the angle of the colors.

https://jsfiddle.net/ypx4mtnr/4/

```
async function sha256(message) ... see fiddle ...
```

```js
   async function sha256(message) {
    // encode as UTF-8
    const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(message);                    

    // hash the message
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);

    // convert ArrayBuffer to Array
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));

    // convert bytes to hex string                  
    const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
    return hashHex;
   }  
   function sha256tohtml(x,b){
var y=chunkSubstr(x,6);
return '<div style="'+
    'display: inline-block;'+
    'margin:2em;'+
    'width:128px;'+
    'height:128px;'+
    'border-radius: 512px;'+
    'background: conic-gradient('+
    '   from '+((360/65536)*parseInt(y[10],16))+'deg at 50% 50%,'+
    '   #'+y[0]+' '+(0+b)+'%,'+
    '   #'+y[0]+' 10%,'+
    '   #'+y[1]+' '+(10+b)+'%,'+
    '   #'+y[1]+' 20%,'+
    '   #'+y[2]+' '+(20+b)+'%,'+
    '   #'+y[2]+' 30%,'+
    '   #'+y[3]+' '+(30+b)+'%,'+
    '   #'+y[3]+' 40%,'+
    '   #'+y[4]+' '+(40+b)+'%,'+
    '   #'+y[4]+' 50%,'+
    '   #'+y[5]+' '+(50+b)+'%,'+
    '   #'+y[5]+' 60%,'+
    '   #'+y[6]+' '+(60+b)+'%,'+
    '   #'+y[6]+' 70%,'+
    '   #'+y[7]+' '+(70+b)+'%,'+
    '   #'+y[7]+' 80%,'+
    '   #'+y[8]+' '+(80+b)+'%,'+
    '   #'+y[8]+' 90%,'+
    '   #'+y[9]+' '+(90+b)+'%,'+
    '   #'+y[9]+' 100%);"></div>';
  }
   function chunkSubstr(str, size) {
  const numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / size)
  const chunks = new Array(numChunks)

  for (let i = 0, o = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, o += size) {
    chunks[i] = str.substr(o, size)
  }

  return chunks
}
   function draw(x){
    sha256(x).then((x)=>{
        var html=sha256tohtml(x,0);
            document.getElementById('addhere').innerHTML=html;
        });
   }
   window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('sha256string').oninput=function(){draw(this.value);}
        draw(document.getElementById('sha256string').value)
}
```

```html
<html>
<input id="sha256string" value="Hello World">
 <div id="addhere"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### If you are using C# and want HSL colors

Here is a class I wrote based on the [library](https://github.com/zenozeng/color-hash) written by Zeno Zeng and mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28480819/740639) .

The HSLColor class was written by Rich Newman, it is [defined here](https://richnewman.wordpress.com/about/code-listings-and-diagrams/hslcolor-class/)

```cs
    public class ColorHash
    {        
        
        // you can pass in a string hashing function of you choice
        public ColorHash(Func<string, int> hashFunction)
        {
            this.hashFunction = hashFunction;
        }

        // or use the default string.GetHashCode()
        public ColorHash()
        {
            this.hashFunction = (string s) => { return s.GetHashCode(); };
        }
        
        Func<string, int> hashFunction = null;

        static float[] defaultValues = new float[] { 0.35F, 0.5F, 0.65F };

        // HSLColor class is defined at https://richnewman.wordpress.com/about/code-listings-and-diagrams/hslcolor-class/
        public HSLColor HSL(string s) {
            return HSL(s, defaultValues, defaultValues);
        }

        // HSL function ported from https://github.com/zenozeng/color-hash/       
        public HSLColor HSL(string s, float[] saturationValues, float[] lightnessValues)
        {
            
            double hue;
            double saturation;
            double luminosity;

            int hash = Math.Abs(this.hashFunction(s));

            hue = hash % 359;

            hash = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)hash / 360);
            saturation = saturationValues[hash % saturationValues.Length];

            hash = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)hash / saturationValues.Length);
            luminosity = lightnessValues[hash % lightnessValues.Length];

            return new HSLColor(hue, saturation, luminosity);
        }
        
    }
```