# Creating distinct colours from similar numbers, in a reproducible way

Tags: python, user-interface, colors, calendar

I have a booking system for a carpark. For any given day there is a decimal booking rate.

I need to to display a calendar of the rates over the year so the admins can track where the price hikes are, and to quickly check that things are the right price.

I have had the idea of creating a key of colours and mapping them to the distinct rates we use over the year. It's just a bit of CSS to display those on the calendar. That would be beautiful.

At a glance this is really simple:

- I declare number of "distinct enough" colours (map colours are a good start)
- I sort the distinct prices and assign them logically to a colour.

But what happens when Bob from management blunders in and adds a new cheap rate? All the rates get shunted up a colour. Bob hasn't actually broken anything but when the page refreshes, it **looks like** he's changed the entire system. Appearance is important here.

Without a *really* tiresome storing/retrieval process, is there a good way to "hash" my rates into a smallish set of good distinctive/mapping colours?

---

Or is this crazy? Should I just reverse-"heat map" this between min and max so the lowest rate shows white, and the highest a dark red? That's easy to do and Bob's blunders will still have an effect, but they won't rotate the entire bank of colours.

The problem with a heatmap is numbers that are close together in a large range will show as practically the same colour. That's sort of the whole problem I'm trying to solve ☹

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120840/hash-string-into-rgb-color seems related.

Comment: Might take a look at UX stack exchange...

Answer (score 1):

Yup, the [hash/bitwise answers on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120840/hash-string-into-rgb-color) seem to do the right thing.
Here's my python implementation:

```
def colourise(s):
    # Returns a RGB tuple.
    h = hash(str(s))
    return ((h & 0xFF0000) >> 16), ((h & 0x00FF00) >> 8), (h & 0x0000FF)
```

Comment: Damn, hammered as dupe of the other looking at your answer :-( ... Reopened now, sry

Comment: Nothing about this answer guarantees that the colors will be pleasant or distinguishable, but if that's OK for you then go for it.